# "if and as" - Does it mean what I think it means and is it even grammatically sound?

Tags: meaning, grammar

Very infrequently, I'll use the fragment *"if and as"* in a sentence. For instance:

> Having it be double fudge chocolate cake in both cases comes off as needless frippery if and as the recipe is valid in itself.

I *think* I'm using it to mean that the recipe itself can be considered valid by some (*"if"*) and is considered so by me (*"as"*). But this could be either grammatically unsound or not meaning roughly what I want it to mean.

*So is it grammatically sound?*

*Does it convey what I think conveys?*

*If so, does this fragment of three words have a formal name for what it's doing grammatically?*

Comment: How is this better than/different from *if and when*?

Comment: @TimLymington Better is subjective; but Different I answer - [as](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/as) and [when](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/when) are quite different words. 'When' is essentially temporal; 'As' is rather more diverse in possible meanings. "if and when" is just another way of saying "when this may happen"; whilst "if and as" is... well that's the question isn't it?

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard that usage.  I would not know what meaning was intended if I heard it.

Answer (score 1):

[Google NGrams shows that it is used](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=if%20and%20as&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cif%20and%20as%3B%2Cc0), with an interesting peak around 1885, but these days it would seem unusual, and probably not be understood, outside of a legal document. (BrEng)

Comment: I do occasionally see it in legal documents; but with more emphasis on the _"if"_ than the _"as"_ due to the common framing words I've seen it in.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, I'm trying to answer the question. I don't want to say outright "Is it gramatically sound? No. Does it convey what I think conveys? No" because in other variations of English it might be valid.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, it's hard to see how matters of acceptable usage can ever be anything other than opinions. Anyway, edited.